# json encode specific object's property

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have an array:

```
[
    (int) 0 => object(stdClass) {
        key1 => 'aaa'
        key2 => 'bbb'
        key3 => 'ccc'
    },
    (int) 1 => object(stdClass) {
        key1 => 'ddd'
        key2 => 'eee'
        key3 => 'fff'
    },
    (int) 2 => object(stdClass) {
        key1 => 'ggg'
        key2 => 'hhh'
        key3 => 'iii'
    }
]
```

I want to return a json_encode for this array, but only for "key2" and "key3" attributes.

For the moment that:

```
foreach($myArray as $key){
    unset($key->key1);
}
```

But this is not okay as the array may also contain other properties. If it is possible, I prefer not to use loops...

(sorry for my english)

Comment: One way or another there will be loops involved. Why the dislike?

Comment: You could look into `array_map` function..

Comment: @KIKOSoftware> You are probably right. It's strange but in my eyes the loops are "ugly".

Comment: A loop is nothing more than a way to repeat a piece of code. Computers are very good at doing that. It's a basic tool in your toolkit. A loop is also quite easy to understand. Seeing them as "ugly" is weird. Where did that come from? You have to be careful about having such subjective opinions about code, they are not helpful and could make you a bad programmer. You do realize that `array_map()` also loops over the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-map.php) and [`array_intersect_key()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-intersect-key.php):

```php
<?php

$data = [
  ['key1' => 'aaa', 'key2' => 'bbb', 'key3' => 'ccc'],
  ['key1' => 'ddd', 'key2' => 'eee', 'key3' => 'fff'],
  ['key1' => 'ggg', 'key2' => 'hhh', 'key3' => 'iii']
];

/**
 * define allowed keys
 *
 * array_flip() exchanges the keys with their values
 * so it becomes ['key2' => 0, 'key3' => 1]
 * useful for array_intersect_key() later on
 *
 */
$allowed = array_flip(['key2', 'key3']);

$newData = array_map(
  function($item) use ($allowed) {
    return array_intersect_key($item, $allowed); 
  }, 
  $data
);

echo json_encode($newData);
```

...which prints:

```
[{"key2":"bbb","key3":"ccc"},{"key2":"eee","key3":"fff"},{"key2":"hhh","key3":"iii"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using `array_map` over the array and creating a new array of objects with only the attributes you want.

```
<?php

$arr = [
    ['key1' => 'aaa','key2' => 'bbb','key3' => 'ccc'],
    ['key1' => 'ddd','key2' => 'eee','key3' => 'fff'],
    ['key1' => 'ggg','key2' => 'hhh','key3' => 'iii']
];

$obj = json_decode(json_encode($arr)); // to turn sample data into objects

$output = array_map(function ($e) {
    $new_obj = new stdClass;
    $new_obj->key2 = $e->key2;
    $new_obj->key3 = $e->key3;
    return $new_obj;
}, $obj);

var_dump($output);
```

Results in

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (2) {
    ["key2"]=>
    string(3) "bbb"
    ["key3"]=>
    string(3) "ccc"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
    ["key2"]=>
    string(3) "eee"
    ["key3"]=>
    string(3) "fff"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#7 (2) {
    ["key2"]=>
    string(3) "hhh"
    ["key3"]=>
    string(3) "iii"
  }
}
```